# Before the android app starts the process ggets termiated

Tags: java

01/20 13:04:02: Launching app:

```
$ adb shell am start -n
 "com.tp468.dell.automatedfishpondmonitoringsystem/com.tp468.dell.automatedfishpondmonitoringsystem.MainActivity"
-a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

> Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
>   Waiting for process to come online
>   Timed out waiting for process to appear on huawei-rne_l22-G9UDU18821003178